# Codeigniter $this->db->trans_begin(); if not committed or rolled back and page is refreshed it locks the db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I have a page where `$this->db->trans_begin();` is used and some insertions are done. Then a modal opens and asks user to confirm and if confirmed by user it commits the transaction else rolls. But if the modal opens before committing or roll back happening I refresh he browser. On following the same thing 3 to 4 times the browser hangs as tables gets locked...

Does anybody knows how in case the transaction is open in `codeigniter` and page is refreshed I can close it before starting a new one?

Comment: How do you get a user response on an open transaction in PHP? If your script execution ends, your open mysql connections should be closed and open transactions should be aborted for you automatically. What table engine do you use for your tables. Typical are MyISAM and InnoDB. What kind of connection type do you use, persistent/non-persistent? My first guess is that you are using a persistent connection. Use a non-persistent one or just abort your pending  transactions before the script ends.

Comment: See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html Change the config value for `pconnect` to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's what transactions are meant to do. You must close or roll-back.

Transactions should only be held open for a short as possible as they can block other activity. You certainly shouldn't be holding an transaction open while waiting for user feedback.

Ask user if certain, then only when they press "ok" begin the transaction, do the work and commit it.